# PHP table in Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, browser

I want to present data from an SQL database on an HTML page. A portion of the code I have is below

````
   ```php
<?php

    include 'connection.php';
    $conn = OpenCon();
    include 'vulntable.php';
    TableInsert()

    if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
        $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
    } else {
        $pageno = 1;
    }
    $no_of_records_per_page = 50;
    $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }

    $total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `vulnerability`";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
    $total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `vulnerability` LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
    $res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
        echo "<div class='table-responsive'><table id='myTable' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
     <thead><tr><th>Vul_name</th>
         <th>Website</th>
         <th>Vendor</th>
         <th>ESB</th>
         <th>CVE</th>
         <th>Date</th>
     </tr></thead><tbody>";
     echo "<tr>
     <td>" . $row['Vul_name']."</td>
         <td>" . $row['Website']."</td>
         <td>" . $row['Vendor']."</td>
         <td>" . $row['ESB']."</td>
         <td>" . $row['CVE']."</td>
         <td>" . $row['date_reported']."</td>
     </tr>"; 

     echo "</tbody></table></div>";

    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
````

When getting displayed through a browser though it comes shows as shown here:

[image: shown here]

My assumptions as to why the issue is occurring is due to the greater tha symbol ">" "exiting" the <?PHP portion of the code and therefore the lines aren't able to be read as PHP. I have attempted to put more 'echo' in every line however that did not work.

Comment: Are you sure the PHP is actually being executed, even? Things to check: Is PHP installed properly on your webserver? Did you give your file a .PHP extension? Did you make sure to request the script via http:// rather than file://?

Comment: First, check if the PHP code is even executed. Then show us the piece of code that it displayed instead of being executed. Maybe you have put PHP code inside of a string.

Comment: Yes, good point. use the View Source feature of your browser to show precisely what was sent by the server, rather than relying on what's rendered into the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

In the image showing your result, there is `";` showing before the `while` starts. I'm guessing somewhere in the code above there is some code that is not properly terminated, so that `";` should be closing some expression but instead it's opening your code as a new string. You should do a careful search above it to find the culprit, it's not in the code you posted here.

Comment: I've updated the image and put the full php code in. Are you able let me know? I think all are terminated correctly.

Comment: I don't see `mysqli_close($conn)` in your updated code

Answer (score 0):

I think you have excess use of concat operator.

> also add ; after TableInsert();

```
    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>
    <table id='myTable' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
     <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Vul_name</th>
         <th>Website</th>
         <th>Vendor</th>
         <th>ESB</th>
         <th>CVE</th>
         <th>Date</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>";
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
       echo "<tr>
       <td>" . $row['Vul_name']."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Website']."</td>
        <td>" . $row['Vendor']."</td>
        <td>" . $row['ESB']."</td>
        <td>" . $row['CVE']."</td>
        <td>" . $row['date_reported']."</td>
       
       </tr>";
    
    
    
    }
    
    echo "
    
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    ";
```

Comment: Hi, are you able to please elaborate on how/where. Be sure to be as helpful as possible :)